# Python multiprocessing is not giving expected results

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am new to multiprocessing with python, I was following a course and i find thatthe code is not working as they say in the tutorials. for example:
this code :

```
import multiprocessing 
  
# empty list with global scope 
result = [] 
  
def square_list(mylist): 
    """ 
    function to square a given list 
    """
    global result 
    # append squares of mylist to global list result 
    for num in mylist: 
        result.append(num * num) 
    # print global list result 
    print("Result(in process p1): {}".format(result)) 
  
if __name__ == "__main__": 
    # input list 
    mylist = [1,2,3,4] 
  
    # creating new process 
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=square_list, args=(mylist,)) 
    # starting process 
    p1.start() 
    # wait until process is finished 
    p1.join() 
  
    # print global result list 
    print("Result(in main program): {}".format(result))
```

should print this result  as they say in the tutorial:

```
Result(in process p1): [1, 4, 9, 16]
Result(in main program): []
```

but when I run it it prints

```
Result(in main program): []
```

I think the prosses did not even start.
I am using python 3.7.9 from anaconda.
how to fix this ?

Comment: Could not reproduce. Check your code thoroughly. Make sure your subprocess is started with `p1.start()`

Comment: I don't know what happened on your side, but it's working perfectly fine for me.

Comment: IDEs don't always capture the output of other processes.  They may redirect the `stdout` of the main process but the child processes don't inherit the change.  Run it from a command line console instead, or have it write the output to a file to prove to yourself that the process ran.

Comment: are you running it using spider? or jupyterLab ? or just execute the file ?

Comment: Is that the way `global` should work?

Comment: There may be a difference between Linux and Windows. What operating system are people using?

Comment: @Peter yes, the global variable is unique to each processs, so it prints an empty list from the main program because it was only modified in the subprocess, which was probably the point of the tutorial.  The OP didn't see the print from the subprocess, though, and that is typically due to using an IDE that only captures stdout from the main process.

Answer (score -1):

Do not use global Variables which you access at the same time. Global Variables are most of the time a very bad idea and should be used very carefully.
The easiest way is to use `p.map`. (you don't have to start/join the processes)

```
with Pool(5) as p:
   result=p.map(square_list,mylist)
```

If you do not want to use `p.map` you can use also `q.put()` to return the value and `q.get()` to get the value from the function

You can find also examples for getting the result in multiprocessed function here:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's issue.  The tutorial's output expected the global not to be modified in the main program.  Likely it was demonstrating how globals aren't "global" in multiprocessing.  OP's issue was not seeing the print from the subprocess.